# Hibernate JoinTable uses OUTER JOIN in case of lazy collection

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

as you can see I have OneToMany collection using additional join table. The `CustomerAccountTransaction` is a owner and `Invoice` is a child.. In other words transaction can contain a lot of invoices.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customeraccounttransactions")
public class CustomerAccountTransaction {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "transaction")
    private List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>(0);
}    
@Entity

@Table(name = "invoices")
public class Invoice {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "customeraccounttransaction2invoices", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "InvoiceId") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "AccountTransactionId") })
    private CustomerAccountTransaction transaction;
}
```

The issue is the following: when I try to retrieve a list of invoices (without "touching" transaction field) the hibernate always puts LEFT OUTER JOIN to `customeraccounttransaction2invoices`. It just ignores the FetchType.LAZY!

Code:

```
public List<Invoice> getList(final String filter, final Long customerId, final Invoices queryType, final Sort sort, final Integer page, final Integer perPage) {
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, false);
        List<Invoice> result = null;

        Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Invoice.class)
                .addOrder(sort.getType() == SortType.Asc ? Order.asc(sort.getField()) :  Order.desc(sort.getField()));

        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(filter)) {
            String f = String.format("%%%s%%", filter.trim());

            query.createAlias("request", "request")
                .createAlias("request.person", "person")
                .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("request.number", f))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("person.firstName", f))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("person.lastName", f))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("number", f))
            );
        }
        if (customerId != null) {
            query.createAlias("customer", "customer")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("customer.id", customerId));
        }
        switch (queryType) {
            case Active:
                query.add(Restrictions.ne("type", InvoiceType.Proforma))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("paid", false))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("cancelled", false));
                break;
            case Paid:
                query.add(Restrictions.eq("paid", true));
                break;
        }
        if (page != null && perPage != null) {
            query.setFirstResult((page - 1) * perPage);
            query.setMaxResults(perPage);
        }

        result = query.list();
        if (result == null)
            result = new ArrayList<Invoice>();

        return result;
    }
```

SQL:

```
select
        this_.Id as Id51_0_,
        this_.CreationTime as Creation2_51_0_,
        this_.CreatorId as CreatorId51_0_,
        this_.ModificationTime as Modifica3_51_0_,
        this_.ModificatorId as Modific17_51_0_,
        this_.CancellationTime as Cancella4_51_0_,
        this_.Cancelled as Cancelled51_0_,
        this_.CancellerId as Cancell18_51_0_,
        this_.Currency as Currency51_0_,
        this_.CustomerId as CustomerId51_0_,
        this_.Description as Descript6_51_0_,
        this_.InProcess as InProcess51_0_,
        this_.Number as Number51_0_,
        this_.Paid as Paid51_0_,
        this_.PartnerId as PartnerId51_0_,
        this_.PaymentDate as Payment10_51_0_,
        this_.PaymentTillDate as Payment11_51_0_,
        this_.PaymentType as Payment12_51_0_,
        this_.CustomerPersonId as Custome22_51_0_,
        this_.ProcessorId as Process23_51_0_,
        this_.ProformaInvoiceId as Proform24_51_0_,
        this_.RequestId as RequestId51_0_,
        this_.RequestServiceId as Request26_51_0_,
        this_.TotalAmount as TotalAm13_51_0_,
        this_.TotalVatAmount as TotalVa14_51_0_,
        this_.Type as Type51_0_,
        this_1_.AccountTransactionId as AccountT1_52_0_ 
    from
        invoices this_ 
    left outer join
        customeraccounttransaction2invoices this_1_ 
            on this_.Id=this_1_.InvoiceId 
    where
        this_.Paid=? 
    order by
        this_.Number asc limit ?
```

The question is why?
Thank you in advance

UPD #1: Basically because of the this_1_.AccountTransactionId as AccountT1_52_0_ in fields list the query returns duplicates... It is a main problem.

Comment: We cannot believe just so. You have to show us a JPA/Hibernate query (or operation, like fetch/EntityManager.find()) and the corresponding SQL query. Did you make sure the query does not come from other things?

Comment: It has to be @ManyToMany on the 'transaction' property. Check it here.  http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: It is not solves the duplicates issue that I am facing.. outer join still there..

Comment: I would try to select only distinct `Invoice`s: `criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);`

Comment: Yes, it might be a solution but in case of selection by ID it will fail once again because of the duplicate...

Comment: I don't get it: what duplicate in case of distinct?

Comment: My point is that I will have to put Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY in all queries connected to this entity.. And this is not correct solution I believe

Comment: How many queries do you have? Please try at least to check if this works, just to identify a solution (before checking for other solutions).

Comment: It works) But I think I will change the whole scheme in order to get rid of this JoinTable

Answer (score 0):

The association is optional. For doc reference http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join
`inner join` would return no results if there are no entries in `customeraccounttransaction2invoices`

You can try setting `optional` to `false`

Comment: Same result.. Duplicates in a result